# When someone types in a word with 2-20 characters in into txtusername I want progressbar1 to =100

Tags: vb.net, string

I can make the progress bar equal `100` if someone enters a specific word into `txtUsername` by writing:

```
Dim word1 As String = "14TSmith"

If txtUsername = word1 Then 
    progressbar1.value = 100
End If
```

(sorry I can't copy and paste the exact code because it is on another system)

But I want the user to type in any string that is between `2-20` characters long, not just a specific word.

Comment: Use the [Length](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.length(v=vs.110).aspx) property. if txtusername.length >= 2 and txtusername.length <= 20 then progressbar1.value= 100

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
If txtusername.TextLength >= 2 And txtusername.TextLength <= 20 Then
   ProgressBar1.Value = 100
End If
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: The code worked when I changed .length to .textlength just to let u know, thanks for the code

Answer (score 1):

If you want to give the user feedback of how "good" their password is based on the length, then:

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Const MinLength As Integer = 2
    Private Const MaxLength As Integer = 20

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        TextBox1.MaxLength = MaxLength
    End Sub

    Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged
        Dim Percent As Double
        If TextBox1.TextLength < MinLength Then
            Percent = 0
        Else
            Percent = CDbl(TextBox1.TextLength) / CDbl(MaxLength)
        End If
        Dim value As Integer = ProgressBar1.Minimum + (ProgressBar1.Maximum - ProgressBar1.Minimum) * Percent
        ProgressBar1.Value = Math.Max(Math.Min(value, ProgressBar1.Maximum), ProgressBar1.Minimum)
    End Sub

End Class
```